# After removing bullet points using regex getting extra space between characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regular expression to remove certain set of things like `bullet points` from my text and I am able to remove that using the following code:

```
 mystr = mystr.replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, ' ');
```

But unfortunately when I am giving text for example `"abc def"` I am getting extra space between characters.

What I getting the out put is like: `"a b c d e f"`.

Please guide me to correct it in such a way that it wont affect my logic for removing bullet point and othe stuffs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing even on "empty character", which is what `*` means at the end when there are 0 occurrences.

Try to replace it with `+`, which means "one or more"

Comment: Good call!  Now, if `+` is used as suggested, that does mean that "one *or more*" occurrences of (adjacent) characters will be replaced by *one* blank space.  Another possibility would be to use no repetition-indicator at all:  neither `+` nor `*`.  This will replace "one character" with "one blank."  It just depends on what you want to do.  (Clearly, the OP was replacing "nothing" with "one blank," and that's not what s/he meant to be doing.)

Comment: Yes, This is indeed worth mentioning. I actually read it wrong and assumed OP wanted to replace with empty string here to remove it. I see now that it doesn't, so thanks for that addendum.